# Clarifying overloaded graphics terminology

Tags: android, linux, graphics, opengl-es

I've been hearing various graphics terminology for years now through other people having conversations at work but every time I try to get a basic understanding I find it difficult because it seems like a lot of the terminology is overloaded and means different things in different contexts. I've been trying to understand this from a Linux/Android perspective in case that matters. I'm really trying to understand the Android graphics architecture but in reading through a lot of material I'm going in circles because of the terms below.

Rendering - The wikipedia definition refers to the graphics pipeline that creates a 2D raster representation of a 3D scene. I also hear the term render used to refer to display something on the screen, i.e. "render to the screen".

Texture - I've looked up the OpenGL definition but I seem to hear people use surface and texture interchangeably sometimes, neither of which I understand.

Surface - I've seen an Android definition saying a surface is an object holding pixels that are composited to the screen. However, I think in graphics/OpenGL parlance this means something different.

Framebuffer - I'm familiar with the Linux kernel framebuffer abstraction but the OpenGL definition seems different. What's confusing is that OpenGL "default framebuffer" definition I found seems to be close to that of the Linux kernel framebuffer but I don't think they are referring to the same thing.

Comment: Are you asking about the "Android graphics architecture" or OpenGL? Because the answers aren't necessarily the same thing for both.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the Android graphics architecture which uses OpenGL ES for composition and rendering. I hope once I clarify the OpenGL terminology things will make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering: The process of turning abstract data into a concrete picture

Texture: A [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) mapping between two sets A and B, defined by a set of discrete samples at regular grid coordinates A to values in set B. Really, it's something that abstract. In practice a texture is an n-dimensional pixel based image with pixel values being in a m-dimensional space. Typical values for n and m are 4.

Surface: In computer graphics term a, well, "surface" from which image data can be read from and written to interchangeably.

Framebuffer: In general terms the combination of a region of memory and a logical description how this memory can be interpreted as a n-dimensional image. In Linux the framebuffer abstraction gives you a region of memory that's attached to display output and combines it with the information of how that memory is laid out to make a surface. In OpenGL a framebuffer is also a region of memory together with layout information. There's a default framebuffer, which OpenGL does *not* manage itself, but gets handed down by the operating system. And then you can create custom framebuffers by taking OpenGL image objects (render buffers, textures) and make them the memory of a framebuffer.